# fedpkg local error: conflict

Tags: linux, dependencies, fedora, conflict

When I execute the command "fedpkg local" I get this error message

```
[root@localhost kernel]# fedpkg local
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fedora/client/bodhi.py:48: DeprecationWarning: fedora.client.bodhi has been deprecated. Please use bodhi.client.bindings instead.
  DeprecationWarning)
error: Failed build dependencies:
    rpm < 4.13.0.1-19 conflicts with kernel-4.12.0-0.rc3.git3.2.fc27.x86_64
```

How can I solve the conflict so that I can run `fedpkg` local?

Comment: What fedora version are you using? What package and version are you trying to build. You can try `fedpkg mockbuild` if you want to build something further from your Fedora release.

Comment: Fedora 25. I'm trying to clone my kernel. So I did fedpkg clone -a kernel, then make release, and when I tried to do fedpkg local, I get that message

Comment: If you did just `fedpkg clone`, you are building Fedora Rawhide (27) kernel, not your kernel. Run `git checkout f25` to change to Fedora 25 branch and build your kernel. The Rawhide can be already incompatible with some of your userspace.

Comment: So far so good! I tried that, and fedpkg local is currently running, but not yet finished. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you did just `fedpkg clone`, you are building Fedora Rawhide (27) kernel, not your kernel (Fedora 25). Run `git checkout f25` to change to Fedora 25 branch and now you will be able to build your kernel using `fedpkg local`. The Rawhide can be already incompatible with some of your userspace you have installed.